# Issues with Concourse Pipeline sh: build/public/maintenance-page/ci-setup-start.sh: Permission denied

Tags: yaml, concourse

I get following error message when running the Concourse Pipeline

sh: build/public/maintenance-page/ci-setup-start.sh: Permission denied

The problem appeared shortly after changing the path from

```
build/maintenance-page/ci-setup-start.sh
```

to

```
build/public/maintenance-page/ci-setup-start.sh
```

I found this in the yaml file for the pipeline.

```
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
          - -exc
          - apk add --no-cache --no-progress bash && build/public/maintenance-page/ci-setup-start.sh
```

Could it be something to do with this and how could I fix the problem?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be missing the execution permission in the script file.

```sh
chmod +x build/public/maintenance-page/ci-setup-start.sh
```

Comment: Hello Danilopopeye,

thank you very much for your help. :)